# How can my website log a vistor into a 3rd party website?

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript

My clients wants to put it on his website a button that fires an action on a 3rd party website they don't host or have access to the server, which means now the code has to be embedded in the HTML code.

The button is not public, it's a generic logon for certain employees.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Add a Lead</title>
</head>
<script type="text/vbscript">
    sub Execute()
        Dim IE
    Dim WRI
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 IE.Visible = 1 
 IE.navigate "http://rentalapp.zillow.com/"
 Do While (IE.Busy)
   WScript.Sleep 10
 Loop
 Set WRI = IE.document.getElementByID("username")
 WRI.Value = "username"
 Set WRI = IE.document.getElementByID("password")
 WRI.Value = "password"
 Set WRI = IE.document.Forms(0)
 WRI.Submit
WScript.Sleep 1000
IE.navigate "http://rentalapp.zillow.com/leads/add/"
end sub    
</script>
<body>
    <button onClick="Execute()">Add A Lead</button>
    This is supposed to fire off the method called execute.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: this *sounds* like the client has asked for a button on their website that, when clicked, will enter the client's username and password into a form, thus logging them in. This sounds like a bad idea! If they want this button on a *public* website, then it is even worse! If the client wants a push-button sign on, look into OpenID. Or maybe just increase the timeout on the site's authentication cookie.  Can you clarify what the client is actually asking for here?  Maybe we can help with suggestions to the real problem, if we know what the real problem is.

Comment: The button is not public, its a generic logon for certain employees, its merely to cut out the time for people to log into each site they have to deal with. None of this info is public. I'm not sure if going another route is worth the time, I'd really rather just try to figure this out because I am almost certain it can work. I have already figured out how to navigate using JavaScript so lastly how to input log in credentials and I'll be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting it to JavaScript won't help. Operating from inside a browser gives you completely different APIs and security restrictions then you get from controlling the browser from the outside.

If any solution is going to work for this problem, it is a simple HTML form with the action set to the site that you want to login to (and a submit button with some hidden inputs).

If that site implements CSRF protection on its login form, then you cannot achieve the desired effect.